# Dart map: Cannot retrieve item from with the same key it was added with

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Bank` `class` which contains `exchange rates`. I **can add** items into the map but **cannot retrieve** the value with the same key I used to put inside the map.

```
class Bank {


  Map<Map<String, String>, double> _exchangeRates = Map();

  void addExchangeRate(String from, String to, double i) {
    _exchangeRates[{from: to}] = i;
  }

  double getExchangeRate(String from, String to) {
    return _exchangeRates[{from, to}];
  }

}

 void main(){
  Bank bank = Bank();
      bank.addExchangeRate("USD", "CHF", 2);
      bank.addExchangeRate("INR", "USD", 1 / 60);
      bank.addExchangeRate("INR", "NRS", 160/100);
      print(bank.getExchangeRate("USD","CHF"));
      print(bank.getExchangeRate("INR","USD"));
      print(bank.getExchangeRate("INR","NRS"));
}
```

**Output :**

```
null
null
null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, in `Dart` everything is an object and the `Map` you are seeking for is not same `Object` the `Map` you are searching with. So you are getting null. You need advanced methods for this.

This is the solution:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class Bank {
  Function equals = const MapEquality().equals;
  Map<Map<String, String>, double> _exchangeRates = Map();

  void addExchangeRate(String from, String to, double i) {
    _exchangeRates[{from: to}] = i;
  }

  double getExchangeRate(String from, String to) {
    return _exchangeRates[_exchangeRates.keys.firstWhere((entry){
      return equals(entry, {from : to});
    })];
  }
}

void main() {
  Bank bank = Bank();
  bank.addExchangeRate('USD', 'CHF', 2);
  bank.addExchangeRate('INR', 'USD', 1 / 60);
  bank.addExchangeRate('INR', 'NRS', 160 / 100);
  print(bank.getExchangeRate('USD', 'CHF'));
  print(bank.getExchangeRate('INR', 'USD'));
  print(bank.getExchangeRate('INR', 'NRS'));
}
```

Comment: I see @diegoveloper but my answer is different and sometimes you may need to use Map inside Map you know :) Let's keep this answer for future.

Comment: sure, it's okay, I prefer to keep things simple as it's in this case

Comment: This answer's the question even though I don't need it.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are using objects as Keys, but when you try to retrieve the values you are creating new objects, so the result value is null.

I would use `String` as a Key composed by `from` and `to` values, like this:

```
class Bank {

  Map<String, double> _exchangeRates = Map();

  void addExchangeRate(String from, String to, double i) {
    _exchangeRates["$from$to"] = i;
  }

  double getExchangeRate(String from, String to) {
    return _exchangeRates["$from$to"];
  }

}

void main() {
Bank bank = Bank();
      bank.addExchangeRate("USD", "CHF", 2);
      bank.addExchangeRate("INR", "USD", 1 / 60);
      bank.addExchangeRate("INR", "NRS", 160/100);
      print(bank.getExchangeRate("USD","CHF"));
      print(bank.getExchangeRate("INR","USD"));
      print(bank.getExchangeRate("INR","NRS"));
}
```

Comment: Had been seeing this counter you can accept in 2 min, 1 min, 38 seconds, 2 seconds. And finally the green tick.. cheers

Answer (score 2):

As a third option, I'll suggest using a `Map` with a non-standard equality. That is one of the uses that the `MapEquality` from package `collection` is intended for.

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class Bank {
  static const _me = MapEquality();
  Map<Map<String, String>, double> _exchangeRates = 
      Map(equals: _me.equals, hashCode: _me.hash);

  void addExchangeRate(String from, String to, double i) {
    _exchangeRates[{from: to}] = i;
  }

  double getExchangeRate(String from, String to) =>
      _exchangeRates[{from: to}];
}

void main() {
  Bank bank = Bank();
  bank.addExchangeRate('USD', 'CHF', 2);
  bank.addExchangeRate('INR', 'USD', 1 / 60);
  bank.addExchangeRate('INR', 'NRS', 160 / 100);
  print(bank.getExchangeRate('USD', 'CHF'));
  print(bank.getExchangeRate('INR', 'USD'));
  print(bank.getExchangeRate('INR', 'NRS'));
}
```

This makes the lookup more efficient because it does hash-based lookup instead of linear search.
There is still the overhead of creating a new map for each lookup.

It seems the "map" here is really just a *pair*. A `Map` is a high-cost abstraction for storing just a single pair, and it doesn't have a natural equality. The suggestion of using `"$from$to"` as key is better than using a key. If you need to separate the values later, you could also use a new class containing the two strings, and with an equals and hash code to match, like:

```
class _StringPair {
  final String first;
  final String second;
  _StringPair(this.first, this.second);
  int get hashCode => (first.hashCode * 37 + second.hashCode * 17) & 0x3FFFFFFF;
  bool operator==(Object other) => 
      other is _StringPair && first == other.first && second == other.second;
}
```

Then use `StringPair(from,to)` that as keys instead of `{from: to}`.